# cant get contacts data from htc(4.3.1) android

Tags: android

I am not able to find any appropriate solution for below issue. I have some method which return contact names and phone numbers from phone, and it works on lots of devices.

But, **problem** is this method does not work on my htc(android 4.3.1). I think, **maybe main cause is** on line of declaration of cursor(Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);), because I checked Cursor object by getCount method and it showed me a zero, which means it could not get any data. I tried many ways of declaring Cursor object, but I didn't succeed.

thanks in advance! Please check Code mentioned below:

```
private List<String> getContactNames() {
        List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        // Get the ContentResolver
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        // Get the Cursor of all the contacts
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[()+]", "");
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll(" ", "");
            if (phoneNumber.startsWith("8")) {
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceFirst("8", "7");
            }
            //contactNames.add(phoneNumber);
            contacts.add(name + "&&" + phoneNumber);
        }
        phones.close();
        Collections.sort(contacts, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        List<String> contactList =
                new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(contacts));
        for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
            String tem = contactList.get(i);
            String[] arr = tem.split("&&");
            contactNumbers.add(arr[1]);
            contactNames.add(arr[0]);
        }

        //Toast.makeText(this, contactNames.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return contactList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, main cause was the device itself, I checked other similar applications that use the device contacts as whatsapp, and these applications are also unable to use the phone's contacts. All answers are presented here work perfectly , as good as my method.

Comment: Does this mean you're still unable to read the contacts on your HTC? I noticed the same problem on a HTC 10, but I'm not able to get it right on that specific device.

Comment: @PKuijpers , yeah , it was a malfunction of that specific device, so I gave up testing app on that phone.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
public class ContactsProvider {

private Uri QUERY_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
private String CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
private String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
private Uri EMAIL_CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
private String EMAIL_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
private String EMAIL_DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;
private String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
private String PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
private Uri PHONE_CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
private String PHONE_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
private String STARRED_CONTACT = ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED;
private ContentResolver contentResolver;

public ContactsProvider() {
    contentResolver = GenericApplication.getContext().getContentResolver();
}

public List<Contact> getContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    String[] projection = new String[]{CONTACT_ID, DISPLAY_NAME, HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, STARRED_CONTACT};
    String selection = null;
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(QUERY_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Contact contact = getContact(cursor);
        contactList.add(contact);
    }

    cursor.close();
    return contactList;
}

private Contact getContact(Cursor cursor) {
    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_ID));
    String name = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME)));
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(QUERY_URI, String.valueOf(contactId));

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(uri);
    String intentUriString = intent.toUri(0);

    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.id = Integer.valueOf(contactId);
    contact.name = name;
    contact.uriString = intentUriString;

    getPhone(cursor, contactId, contact);
    getEmail(contactId, contact);
    return contact;
}

private void getEmail(String contactId, Contact contact) {
    Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EMAIL_CONTENT_URI, null, EMAIL_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contactId}, null);
    while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL_DATA));
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            contact.email = email;
        }
    }
    emailCursor.close();
}

private void getPhone(Cursor cursor, String contactId, Contact contact) {
    int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
    if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
        Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PHONE_CONTENT_URI, null, PHONE_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contactId}, null);
        while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(PHONE_NUMBER));
            contact.phone = phoneNumber;
        }
        phoneCursor.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you added this or not in menifest ?
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: yes, I added, there is no error , I checked cursor object by getCount() method, it was equal to zero, which means that it could not extract contact data ,as I sad before my own method works too, except on my htc phone, and phone has a lot of contacts.

Comment: Ok so due to lot of contact you got issue.

Comment: I think issue is not the quantity of contacts, problem is smth associated with htc ,it does not extract any data of contacts. My method worked on nexus, lenovo, samsung e.t.c ,except htc

Comment: may be depend on CPU structure of device.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
    private void LoadContactsWithPhone() {
    TextView contactView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtContacts);
    contactView.setText("");

    Cursor cursor = getContactsWithPhone();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String phoneNo = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        contactView.append("Name: ");
        contactView.append(displayName);
        contactView.append("\n");

        contactView.append("Phone: ");
        contactView.append(phoneNo);
        contactView.append("\n\n");

    }

}
    private Cursor getContactsWithPhone() {
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    };

    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = ?";

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(1)};

    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

Comment: could you also show getContactsWithPhone() method , which shown here(in your code)?

Answer (score 0):

Please used the following code its working on my end on all devices:-

```
  public ArrayList<Contact_Model> getContacts(){

    ArrayList<Contact_Model> contact_models = new ArrayList<>();
    //        ContentResolver cr = context.getActivity().getContentResolver();
            ContentProviderClient mCProviderClient = context.getActivity().getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            Cursor cur = mCProviderClient.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    Contact_Model contact_model = new Contact_Model();
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String firstname;
                    String lastName = "";
                    if (name != null) {

                        contact_model.setContactId(id);
                        contact_model.setContactName(name);
                        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                            // get the phone number
                            Cursor pCur = mCProviderClient.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                    new String[]{id}, null);

                            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                                String phone = pCur.getString(
                                        pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                contact_model.setContactNumber(phone);
                            }
                            pCur.close();


                            // get email and type

                            Cursor emailCur = mCProviderClient.query(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                    new String[]{id}, null);

                            while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                                // This would allow you get several email addresses
                                // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                                String email = emailCur.getString(
                                        emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                                contact_model.setContactEmail(email);
                            }
                            emailCur.close();

                            Cursor photoCursor = mCProviderClient.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                    new String[]{id}, null);
                            while (photoCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                String photo = photoCursor.getString(photoCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID));
                                if (photo == null) {
                                    contact_model.setContactPhoto("");
                                } else {
                                    contact_model.setContactPhoto(photo);
                                }

                            }
                            contact_model.setContactOtherDetails("");
                            photoCursor.close();

                            // Get note.......
                            String noteWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                            String[] noteWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                            Cursor noteCur = mCProviderClient.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, noteWhere, noteWhereParams, null);
                            if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) {
                                String note = noteCur.getString(noteCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));
                                System.out.println("Note " + note);
                                contact_model.setNote(note);
                            }

                            noteCur.close();

                            // Get Organizations.........

                            String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                            String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                            Cursor orgCur = mCProviderClient.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
                            if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                                String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
                                String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
                                if (orgName != null) {
                                    contact_model.setOrganization(orgName);
                                }
                                if (title != null) {
                                    contact_model.setJob(title);
                                }
                            }
                            orgCur.close();

                        }

                        contact_models.add(contact_model);
                    }
                }
            }
            return contact_models;

    }



Contact Model:-

public class Contact_Model implements Serializable {

    private String contactId = "", contactName = "", contactNumber = "", contactEmail = "", contactPhoto = "", contactOtherDetails = "";

    private String firstName = "", lastName = "", note = "", organization = "", job = "", dob = "";

    ContactAccount contactAccount;

    public Contact_Model() {

    }



    public Contact_Model(String contactId, String contactName, String contactNumber, String contactEmail, String contactPhoto, String contactOtherDetails, String firstName, String lastName,
                         String note, String organization, String job, String dob) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
        this.contactName = contactName;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.contactEmail = contactEmail;
        this.contactPhoto = contactPhoto;
        this.contactOtherDetails = contactOtherDetails;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.note = note;
        this.organization = organization;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.job = job;
    }

    public ContactAccount getContactAccount() {
        return contactAccount;
    }

    public void setContactAccount(ContactAccount contactAccount) {
        this.contactAccount = contactAccount;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public String getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(String organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }

    public void setContactId(String contactId) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
    }

    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    public String getContactEmail() {
        return contactEmail;
    }

    public void setContactEmail(String contactEmail) {
        this.contactEmail = contactEmail;
    }

    public String getContactPhoto() {
        return contactPhoto;
    }

    public void setContactPhoto(String contactPhoto) {
        this.contactPhoto = contactPhoto;
    }

    public String getContactOtherDetails() {
        return contactOtherDetails;
    }

    public void setContactOtherDetails(String contactOtherDetails) {
        this.contactOtherDetails = contactOtherDetails;
    }
}


ContactAccount.class

public class ContactAccount implements Serializable {

    String accountName = "", accountType = "";

    public ContactAccount(){

    }

    public ContactAccount(String accountName, String accountType) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }


    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    public String getAccountType() {
        return accountType;
    }

    public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: ,could you explain me pls, what is the Contact_Model?

Comment: I dont know why, but this code also could not extract contacts from my htc(4.3.1) , have any Idea?

Comment: I am edit my answer plz check the contact model and contact account class. @Bek

Comment: thanks a lot for your recall, problem was from device , not code , all answers posted here work perfectly(including yours), so I cant accept only 1 answer, because all answers are correct:)